# how to remove the shortcut on Finder top bar (see picture)

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu

I don't know how I got these shortcuts on Finder's bar (look on the right). These shortcuts are on every Finder windows. 
How to remove them ? What's those shortcut called ?

This picture is worth more than any description.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press the command key <kbd>⌘</kbd> .
2. **Drag** the item away from the toolbar.

This behavior is generic for other OS X Apps. (Finder, Safari, Pages,...)

Comment: What are these items called ?

Comment: @raychenon Apple refers to them simply as 'items': [see this picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv0ruxql2lr2uat/Items.png)

Answer (score 1):

Secondary-click them (two-finger tap if you've got it configured, otherwise control+click), then select "Remove item".

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the toolbar, select "Customize Toolbar...", then drag them out.